# TypeError when inserting elements from list into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying to insert each value from a list into a database using python, a mysql database and mysqldb. Type for all elements in this list in the database is VARCHAR.

But I'm getting this error:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

The list comprehension is to remove empty strings and in order to try and fix this current issue I've tried to cast each element to a string but it hasn't worked. I've also tried casting it to a string in the query function but hasn't worked either.

value is -3.89738e-05

type(value) is "type 'str'"

```py
for scan in outer:
    scan = [str(x) for x in scan if x]
    for value in scan:
        print value
        print type(value)
        sql_insert = ('INSERT INTO langmuir_data(currentI)'
                      'VALUES("%s")')
        cursor.execute(sql_insert, str(value))
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: And if your query is `sql_insert = """INSERT INTO langmuir_data (currentI) VALUES (%s)"""` and `cursor.execute(sql_insert, (str(value),))` what happens?

Comment: same thing happens, both are valid syntax. I've used that syntax successfully before with other programs and other lists in this program

Comment: Well, in SQL I've used before they would do different things, since you're not passing the parameter as a tuple. You copy/pasted both the lines I wrote?

Comment: didn't see the difference in the second line but have changed it now and it works! thanks, do you wanna add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Why does passing it as tuple change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your parameterized query, it expects the parameters to be passed in an iterable (the tuple that I put in my comment). When you pass multiple parameters, you'll see no problem because it will unpack those into the placeholders you have provided. However, when you pass a single string, that's still iterable in Python and so it attempts to insert that string character-by-character into your prepared statement.

```
for item in ('abc',):
    print item # prints whole string, for which you provided a placeholder

for item in 'abc':
    print item # prints the individual letters, but you only gave 1 placeholder
```

So, you should use the following:

```
cursor.execute(sql_insert, (str(value),))
```